# play soundpool from internal storage

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

i have try several ways to load sound from internal memory using soundpool. first this snipped code how i record sound:

```
url = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
fileName = "/record.3gp";

recorder = new MediaRecorder();  
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);  
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);  
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);  
recorder.setOutputFile(url+fileName));

try {
   recorder.prepare();
   recorder.start();
} 
catch (IOException e) {
   Log.e("sound", "prepare() failed: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

then this is how i play that sound with media player:

```
mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(url+fileName);
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start();
        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                stopSound();
            }
        });
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

my record sound is played and nothing wrong. but for some condition, i need to load with soundpool. these my code that tried to play with soundpool:

```
// method 1
soundMap.put(1, soundPool.load(url+fileName, 1));
soundPool.play(soundMap.get(1), 1, 1, 0, 0, 1.0f);

// method 2
soundId = soundPool.load(soundPool.load(url+fileName, 1), 1);
soundPool.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1.0f)
```

// method 3
change url and follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13219902/1334052)

and all of these result nothing. i tried to check using this code:

```
Log.d("sound", "soundpool play: " + soundPool.play(soundId, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1.0f));
```

its result "soundpool play: 0"

Comment: How long are these sounds you're recording and trying to play?

Comment: less than 20 seconds.